# 'float' object is not iterable in for loop

Tags: python, loops, typeerror

I did research solution of this problem for hours but ı can't find any solution. What is the problem in my code?

```
import numpy as np

q_max = 5
for q in range(1, q_max):
    for p in range(0, q_max):
        if q>p:
            #I want to delete duplicates numbers
            a = list(set(p/q))
            print(a)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\gcd.py", line 16, in <module>
    alfa = list(set(p/q))
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `set()` expects an iterable. `p/q` is a `float`, and is not iterable. That line could just be replaced by `a = [p/q]`, but I suspect that's not what you want to do. You should [edit] your question to include what you expect this code to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want unique divisors you have to create your set before you start looping, and then add your values to the set. When you're finished looping, you can print the whole set.

The set will deduplicate values, ignoring `.add()` calls when items already exist in the set (as opposed to the `list`'s `.append()` method).

```
q_max = 5
values = set()

for q in range(1, q_max):
    for p in range(0, q_max):
        if q>p:
            values.add(p/q)

print(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
a = list(set(p/q))
```

`set()` will cast an iterable (and only an iterable) into a `set` object - effectively eliminating duplicates. However, you pass it the result of `p / q`, which is an int divided by an int - a float. The error states you can't pass a float to a function that expects an iterable.

It's unclear why you want to use `set()` or even `list()` here. If your expectation is to divide `p` by `q`, just do that. `a` will be a float you can print.